# Running an Apex Batch

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I created an Apex Batch. I configured it with the schedule jobs in order to run monthly. I want to test if it works or not. Do I have to write a test class for it or execute it in anonymous?

Here is my Apex Batch:

```java
global class RunBatchApex implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    String query;
        
    global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        Query = 'select Credit__c from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()';  
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<account> scope){
        List<User> usrList = new List<User>();
        for(User s : usrList){
            s.Credit__c += 1.5;
            usrList.add(s);
        }
        update usrList;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

And here is the Apex Scheduler:

```java
global class UpdateUsertBatch_Schedular implements Schedulable{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        RunBatchApex uab = new RunBatchApex ();
        database.executebatch(uab);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/Content/apex_batch_2.htm

Comment: Kawtar, did you forget to ask your question ? It's a bit unclear what answer you're expecting, or what problem you're having with the above code.

Comment: I want to test if my code execute correctly in a specific date

Answer (score 1):

There is a section **Testing Batch Apex** in
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm#apex_batch_testing

It contains example of unit test.